# Is it OK to flag a question twice?

Tags: discussion, flags, off-topic

I had flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350050/plugin-to-change-font-with-scrollbar-value) as **off-topic** on Aug 21, 2013. However, this has not been looked into for quite some time now.

I understand it could be due to moderators looking into other flags. Also, I read on Meta Stack Overflow that some issues may take time which require a lot of attention and investigation, like [sock-puppetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_%28Internet%29).

However, I think this is a pretty straightforward flag, and this question ought to be put on hold and eventually deleted as there hasn't been any more responses on this from the OP.

Is it OK to flag this again as **Very low quality** to get moderators' attention or sit on it?  I'm not talking about flagging abuse. Just a gentle reminder to the moderators.

I have checked other similar questions. But this is more of a flag after a considerable period of time. Not immediate flagging.

**EDIT:** The question in topic has been deleted within a day of me posting this question. So I guess my flagging was appropriate and the community has worked on this.

Comment: *Or* you could draw attention to the post in a chat room or here. I've voted to close as OT (external resource recommendation) now.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters As we speak my flag has been accepted as helpful. But i would be happier if the question was closed.

Comment: Hopefully it will be closed without be needing to re-flag.

Comment: Most likely the flag was marked as helpful automatically as people voted to close the question.

Comment: @Marjtin Pieters, your comment actually was the most contructive. No offence to the other replies. Could you put this in the form of an answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: I see that the question i had spoken about has been deleted altogether. SO is an active community indeed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of flagging again, you could bring the post to the attention of people with vote-to-close privileges instead.

Usually, I'd do so by posting a link to the question in a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), but by posting it here on Meta, you've also attracted attention to the question.

I've voted to post the question as Off Topic (it is an external resource request); I see others have done the same already.

Answer (score 5):

Flagging for closure (all of the options under "It doesn't belong here or is duplicate") do not go to moderators anymore, they go into the 3K close vote queue.

Normally, when a close flag is first raised, it supposed to be put at the front of the queue so it gets looked at quickly, but I've seen this question raised several times in the last couple of months, and my belief is if not enough people look at it it will get buried in the close vote queue (which is 74K questions deep now).

You cannot raise a 2nd flag of the same type while your old one is still active, but you can raise a custom flag that will go into the mod queue.  Currently the mods queue is quite large now as well, so a response might not be immediate.  If you do, I would make sure you do explain that you already raised an off-topic flag and it wasn't handled.  The mod still might dismiss your flag because you have an active flag on it, but there is nothing stopping you from doing it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about how the flagging que works

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this question is specific to Stack Overflow or if it's more of a general question about flagging on all Stack Exchange sites.

If we're talking about all sites in the network I can give my philosophy as a moderator on [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/):

If I see a flag from a user asking me to close/delete something, and I don't agree with the flag but I understand that the user is trying to help, I mark the flag "helpful" and take some combination of actions like editing, commenting, or just watching the post to see what develops.

If that same user flags the same post *again* after I haven't taken their actions, I find that rude and annoying and will flat out decline the flag.

If the user often does this, I stop assuming they're trying to be helpful and decline any flag from them unless I am taking the action they request. That is, no more "I see you're asking me to close this question. I don't agree, but you're trying to help, so I'll mark that flag as helpful and take some other action"

This is just my $0.02, so I say: don't flag twice. If the flag doesn't get you the result you want, ask people in chat for support.

Answer (score 2):

Go for it - if the system *lets* you, why not?

I've re-flagged on a number of occasions, but usually only once a flag has been "handled" (or, rather, in my view, mishandled). If you've already flagged it and the flag is pending, then you'll simply get a message that you've already flagged this post (in contrast to the close box which simply won't let you retry), so I'm unsure whether or not your existing flag has any weight added to it, whether it's just dismissed, or what.

So, nothing explodes if you retry, and nothing goes wrong if you can, so do; if the extra flagging causes a nuisance for moderators then the way flags are being submitted on the backend is a problem, and not yours.